# Limit function parameter argument to base class in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, subclass, base-class

Assume the following setup:

```
class BaseClass<T> { }

class SubClass<T>: BaseClass<T> { }

infix operator >-- { associativity left }

func >-- <T>(lhs: BaseClass<T>, rhs: SubClass<T>) {
    // do something here
}
```

What I am looking for is a way to exclude `SubClass` from being used as the `lhs` argument with the operator `>--`. It would be kind of a negative type constraint on a generic argument - i.e., `T: BaseClass where T != Subclass`:

```
func >-- <T, B: BaseClass<T> where B != SubClass<T>>(lhs: B, rhs: SubClass<T>)
```

But it does not appear that there is a `!=` argument that you can supply as a negative type constraint for a generic. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I think I can actually make the question less complicated - I think the following setup gets at exactly the same issue but without some distracting details:

```
class BaseClass { }
class SubClass: BaseClass { }

// This is what I want to be able to do, but don't know how
// or if it is possible:
func doSomething<B: BaseClass where B != SubClass>(arg: B) { }
```

Hope I didn't just confuse everyone more, but the "infix operator" part and the fact that `BaseClass` was a generic `BaseClass<T>` aren't really important to the question...

Comment: But the notion `BaseClass where B != SubClass` completely overrides the substitution principle on which polymorphism is based. It makes no sense whatever (at least not in the object-oriented world I've grown up in - maybe there are other object-oriented architectures I've never used).

Comment: Those are good points. I think it makes more sense as a feature of generics...if the compiler can check to see if an object *is* something, or that it *does conform* to a certain protocol, it would also be useful to check whether an object *is not* something or *does not* conform to a protocol. But I agree with your point about this running contrary to the concept of polymorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot prevent substitution of subclass instance for superclass instance at *compiler* level, as you are trying to do, because that substitution is the *basis* of polymorphism itself.

You are, of course, free to throw a wobbly *at runtime* if the `dynamicType` of the parameter turns out not to be the superclass:

```
func doSomething(arg: BaseClass) {
    if !(arg.dynamicType === BaseClass.self) {
        fatalError("die die die")
    }
    println("ok")
}
```